# Different backgrounds for dual monitor setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8

I have read and seen on videos that support for per-monitor backgrounds have been introduced natively in windows 8, but I cannot seem to find where to change the 2nd monitor background anywhere.

How can I set a different background for each monitor?

**EDIT**
Found the [original blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20151122031120/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2012/05/21/enhancing-windows-8-for-multiple-monitors.aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Right click your desktop, click **Personalize** and then on the bottom row of the Personalize window select **Desktop Background**, you will be able to set the individual backgrounds for your monitors there, as you can see in the example image below.

[image]

Comment: What if span isn't an option from the drop down?

Comment: Sadly this does not work in slideshow mode.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can windows XP do the same ?

Answer (score 4):

You can right-click a picture in the selection dialog and select on which monitor to show it.